# Enable caching for download method of Loopback Storage Component?

Tags: caching, loopbackjs

I'm using Loopback as an backend API, and also using Storage component as an CDN to upload and download image and sound file for my website.
My website using a lot of image from that. But all the image files is not cach-enable.

I want to enable cache by adding a "Cache-Control:max-age=2678400" header to the file but don't know how to do it. Can someone help me or suggest any better solution. I really appreciate it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I have found a workaround using Middleware.
Create a middleware in server/middleware folder:

```
// cache.js
module.exports = function () {

    return function cacheImages(req, res, next) {

        // Check if download file:
        if (req.originalUrl.includes('/api/files/') && req.originalUrl.includes('/download/')) {
            console.log("Here at the middle ware");

            console.log(req.originalUrl);

            res.set('Cache-Control', 'max-age=315360000');
        }

        next();
    }
}
```

and add this middleware in server/middleware.json config file:

```
...
"initial": {
    "./middleware/cache": {}
}
...
```

Hope this help! :)